# IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for array with size 5

Tags: python, arrays

I am using a dataset that I created. It should have 5 classes and it contain 500 samples for training and 100 samples for testing. 
I can't perform this operation:

```
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

as it keep gives me:

```
 Y[i, y[i]] = 1.
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

If I changed the value of classes to 6 it works but this not correct I have 5 classes only.

Please I need  help.

Comment: If you have 5 classes, they are going to be in array elements 0-4, so 5 would be out of bounds.

Comment: Mybe your rage is from 0 to 4.

Comment: the error given is not in my code what I mean I dont have Y[i, y[i]] = 1 in my code ? I am just trying to tell that I have for testign as an example 100 sample and they should be classified into 5 classes so I set the number of classes to 5 and even if I set it to 4 it will give me the same error    only it works with 6 !!

Comment: If the error is not in the code you've shown, we can't find it.

Comment: Y[i, y[i]] = 1.
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5   this part represent the error displayed to my screen and after debugging I found that it occur when reaching to these lines in MY code Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

Comment: I wish you understand my point :)

Answer (score 1):

In many programming languages an index of data structures like arrays starts with 0 (zero). That is, if your structure contains five elements, the index ranges from 0 to 4, and not from 1 to 5.

Therefore, index 5 is out of bounds for a structure with only five elements.